# Does LoadLibrary parse environment variables such as %windir%

Tags: c, winapi, loadlibrary

If I do **`LoadLibrary("%windir%\\system32\\ole32.dll")`** does that mean Windows will ONLY load from "c:\windows\system32\ole32.dll" ? Also does LoadLibrary() in C understand the environment variable?

Comment: No twice, it doesn't expand environment variables and won't understand the escape codes in your string.  And a 32-bit program will be subject to file system redirection on a 64-bit operating system, loading from c:\windows\syswow64 instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as Serge said and carefully tested, LoadLibrary does not do environment variable substitution in path.

however, there is a function in the windows API to replace environment variables in strings: [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). you can perform the required substitution on your path before calling `LoadLibrary()`.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs for LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly state that:

> If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that
>   path for the module.

That said, they don't mention support for environment variables substitution. I seriously doubt they do support environment variables substitution: That's a shell feature, not a kernel API one.

BTW, that means `LoadLibrary()` would consider `%windir%\blah.dll` as a relative path since it doesn't start with a drive letter or a UNC path. Hence it would look through the whole series of directories, looking for a subdir named `%windir%`, which it's not likely to find!

I gave it a quick test: It confirms my opinion. Error = 126 : *The specified module could not be found*.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't expand environment variables.